# RabbitMQ- Application not starting in Windows 10 Home

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed Erlang OTP 23 (11.0) and RabbitMQ Server 3.8.7 on my Windows 10 Home Operating System.
I ran this command- rabbitmq_server-3.8.7\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaWdF.jpg)

After that when I am running localhost:15672/ in my chrome, it's not working. There are no logs inside C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\log

Also, inside services.msc I tried stating RabbitMQ service, but it's go down immediately without any error.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling and also tried all other options available in this forum. But still no luck. Please help me here.

Comment: Check windows event log for errors. Check if what user is running rabbitmq. Does that user have privileges to write to the log?

Comment: @Eiver Event Viewer logs are showing this error- 

Faulting application name: erl.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5ebb20c5
Faulting module name: crypto.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5ebb2227
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\erl-23.0\erts-11.0\bin\erl.exe
Faulting module path: c:\Program Files\erl-23.0\lib\crypto-4.7\priv\lib\crypto.dll
Report Id: 4f4a8817-af73-4e26-937e-2798c296e083
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: @Eiver I am using my personal laptop to install RabbitMq. And I have full admin rights

Comment: Yes you have, but the service might not run as the same user as you do, depending on how you installed it. Go to services and temporarily try to run RabbitMQ as "local system" account if its not running that already. Beware that typically its not good to run services with so much privileges, but it might help to see if it is a permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just install ERL-23.2 x86 package and RabbitMQ 3.8.14
https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-533

Remeber to fix ERLANG_HOME if necessary.